# Why does the Npgsql reverse the tsquery data?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm trying to read `tsquery` data from a PostgreSQL database using Npgsql on C#.

I have a table with one column of `tsquery` type and the data inside looks like this:

```
        a
-----------------
 'a' & 'b'
 'a' <-> 'b'
 'a' & 'b' | 'c'
```

When I read this data using the `GetValue` function the output I get is this:

```
'b' & 'a'
'b' <-> 'a'
'c' | 'b' & 'a'
```

Since `SELECT 'a <-> b'::tsquery = 'b <-> a'::tsquery` returns false in Postgres I thought this might cause problem.

I tried to find any related info on the docs but was not successful. Why is Npgsql reversing the order? Am I missing a parameter or a function?

The code I used to get these results:

```
var connString = "Host=localhost; Username=postgres; Database=postgres; Port=9700;";
using var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();

using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tbl", conn);
using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was cross-posted on github as [this issue](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3230), follow that to track progress.